# When to use the Bootstrap class attribute value ".embed-responsive-item"?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, iframe, twitter-bootstrap-3

hope you might help. I don't understand what exactly the class **".embed-responsive-item"** in the following code snippet (Bootstrap code to make iframes, videos etc. responsive) is actually good for, since it is applied to the iframe element anyway, even if you leave the class attribute value out:

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
<iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="..."></iframe>
</div>
```

Which is actually pretty much the same as (at least from my understanding):

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
<iframe src="..."></iframe>
</div>
```

Why then use it in the first place?

Source: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#responsive-embed

> "optionally use an explicit descendant class .embed-responsive-item when you want to match the styling for other attributes."

What does this quote actually mean? Could you provide an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already found out, there isn't any point. As stated in the docs, and as backed up by looking in `responsive-embed.less`, `.embed-responsive-item` produces the exact same styling as the bare `iframe` element alone.

If perhaps you were using something to generate content which insisted on injecting another layer of markup (e.g. a wrapping `<div/>` between the parent `<div 'embed-responsive'>` and the `<iframe/>`), then that class might prove useful to ensure the expected width / height ratio is honoured.